# IE shows "Windows cannot find https://xxxxxxx" error for download via HTTPS

Tags: java, internet-explorer, jsp, ssl, download

I have a Struts action, which is writing to `HttpServletResponse` as follows. Code only works for HTTP, but not for HTTPS.

```
BufferedInputStream in = null;
try {
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\";");
    // set response headers
    response.setContentLength(fileData.length);
    response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");

    //BUFFER
    int bufferSize = 2 * 1024 * 1024;
    in = new BufferedInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(fileData), bufferSize);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    int len = 0;

    // Loop through the input file and get the data chunks...
    while ((len = in.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) != -1) {
        response.getOutputStream().write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new SystemException(e.getMessage());
} finally {
    response.getOutputStream().flush();
    response.getOutputStream().close();
}
```

Server is Weblogic 10 (does it matter?). Entire web application works with HTTPS, except of the file download.
It does work with Chrome and FF, but not with IE 8/9. The following message is displayed in an alert box

> Windows cannot find 'https://xxxxxxx'

Comment: Did you enable the SSL ports in the container? (Tomcat or equivalent)

Comment: yes, it is enabled on Weblogic 10, entire web application works with HTTPS, except download piece.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known IE-specific problem, see also the Microsoft support site: [Internet Explorer is unable to open Office documents from an SSL Web site](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316431). To fix it, you need to explicitly set the following headers on the response:

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "public");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
```